# How to send data without sigqueue?

Tags: c

I would like to know, how could i send data to another process (from a terminal to another one) using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 but without using the sigqueue function ? i've already searched everywhere on the net but i didn't find any answers to my question.

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways of IPC; pipes, msgsnd, sockets, shared memory, etc.

Comment: Using signals and signals only? You can't. Signals are really not supposed to be a way to transfer data between processes. You need to find some other way of doing the [inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This might be a school assignment, had the same kind of question. We were expected to do this using morse code or something alike to tell the receiving side what data was represented. Might be that ?

Comment: @NaeiKinDus Why would a teacher show how to abuse signals in such a ridiculous way?

Comment: @Ctx beats me ! Guess the guy wanted us to learn about signals, but the exercise is lame and not part of the "real-world-problems" class :-/

Comment: When i say "data" i mean an int, i just need to send a number between 1 and 8 with the signal library, and yes it is a school assignment. maybe the sigqueue function is forbiden because it would be too easy..

Answer (score 0):

For a very simple and basic solution, you could write the data to a file and then send the signal to the process. The receiving process then reads the contents of the file and deletes the file.

This could lead to data-races of course, but is very simple to implement.